# HTML: Unable to find an error

Tags: html, wordpress

When I'm viewing my site with Chrome or Egde, I'm getting an HTML error in the sidebar (The whole sidebar isn't clickable). I've tried to find the error with **validator.w3.org** - but I wasn't that successful.

[Maybe someone can take a look at it - would be very nice.](https://en.unicstack.com/article/read-id=196) (It's a Wordpress site)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This site is a Q&A site for *specific* programming questions.  It's not a site to ask for free debugging.  If you could show an *example* in the question (not just a link) of the issue and how you've tried to debug it, we'd be happy to help.  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it/254430

Comment: Ok I'm sorry I will try to make it more relevant to other next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I got it to work!!

Change the css for `#sidebar` from saying `z-index: -1` to say `z-index: 5` or any high number. It is under the media query having a webkit minimum pixel ratio of 0.

-1 means it would be behind other elements making you click the element in front of it. So having a higher number means it is going to be on top of the page instead behind something.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yea thanks man! :) But I was quicker - and if someone is interested, I have no idee why this css is there